# How do I update entity with ModelMapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have a method like this

```
public void updateEntity(String id) {
.....
.....
  Person person = personRepository.findById(id);
  StudentDTO studentDTO = studentService.getStudent(id); //This returns StudentDTO for the given id

  Person updatedPerson = personService.updatePerson(person, studentDTO);

  personRepository.save(updatedPerson);
}

public Person updatePerson(Person person, StudentDTO studentDTO) {
  ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
  modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);
  modelMapper.typeMap(StudentDTO.class, Person.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
    mapper.map(StudentDTO::getId, PersonDTO::setId);
    mapper.map(src -> PersonUtil.getTaskName(src.getTaskInfo), Person::setTaskName);
  })

  return modelMapper.map(studentDTO, Person.class);
}
```

I am facing two issues with this code.

- Its not updating the Person entity. Rather it is just setting the values of StudentDTO and assigning null values to those properties of Person entity which are not available in StudentDTO.
- For task name, it is setting the entire DTO present inside the TaskInfo property. PersonUtil.getTaskName is the function which takes the object and returns the string taskName but modelmapper for some reason is assigning an entire dto for that field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need an `org.modelmapper.Converter` to assign `taskName`from `taskInfo`.

Assuming `StudentDTO.getTaskInfo()` returns a type `TaskInfo` and `Person.taskName` is of type `String`:

```java
Converter<TaskInfo, String> nameOfTaskInfo = ctx -> PersonUtil.getTaskName(ctx.getSource());
```

...and then...

```java
  modelMapper.typeMap(StudentDTO.class, Person.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
    mapper.map(StudentDTO::getId, Person::setId); // I think this could be skipped
    mapper.using(nameOfTaskInfo).map(StudentDTO::getTaskInfo), Person::setTaskName);
  })
```

But TBH, I am new to ModelMapper too, maybe there are easier solutions.

### Explanation

The purpose of the `map` function seems to determine Getters and Setters through some magic (using byte code manipulated stub objects). The provided expressions are executed when defining the `TypeMap` and not during the actual mapping. The [documentation](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/builder/ReferenceMapExpression.html#map-org.modelmapper.spi.SourceGetter-org.modelmapper.spi.DestinationSetter-) says:

> Map source getter value to destination setter

While on the other hand the `org.modelmapper.Converter` is executed during the mapping.